# UIWebDocumentView _updateSubviewCaches crash in iOS10

Tags: crash, ios10

I am getting the following crash in HockeyApp more seriously in iOS10. Please find the crash log as given below.

Thread 4 Crashed:

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000187242f30 objc_msgSend + 16
1 UIKit 0x000000018e86e914 -[UIWebDocumentView _updateSubviewCaches] + 36
2 UIKit 0x000000018e69093c -[UIWebDocumentView subviews] + 88
3 UIKit 0x000000018e941bd4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) _wantsReapplicationOfAutoLayoutWithLayoutDirtyOnEntry:] + 68
4 UIKit 0x000000018e63d770 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1248
5 QuartzCore 0x000000018bb0640c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
6 QuartzCore 0x000000018bafb0e8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 288
7 QuartzCore 0x000000018bafafa8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
8 QuartzCore 0x000000018ba77c64 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 248
9 QuartzCore 0x000000018ba9f0d0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 508
10 QuartzCore 0x000000018ba9faf0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 116
11 CoreFoundation 0x00000001887a57dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
12 CoreFoundation 0x00000001887a340c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
13 CoreFoundation 0x00000001886d2068 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
14 WebCore 0x000000018d273a2c RunWebThread(void*) + 452
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000018788b860 _pthread_body + 236
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000018788b770 _pthread_start + 280
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000187888dbc thread_start + 0
```

Any idea what is going on here ?
Seems like the following crash groups are also related.

**Crash Group 1**

```
[UIWebBrowserView _collectAdditionalSubviews]
objc_msgSend() selector name: autorelease
```

**Crash Group 2**

```
[UIWebDocumentView subviews]
objc_msgSend() selector name: arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:
```

Comment: Me too, our app encountered a similar crash after iOS 10 update.

Comment: Are you trying to change the frame of an object that has Auto Layout constraints in the app?

Comment: From the crash logs this object can be a WebView , right ? Thats for sure ?

Comment: Could you please give an example ?

Comment: Which of the following do you use: `UIWebView`, `WKWebView`, or `SFSafariViewController`?

Comment: I was using UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering to my own question, since I am able to replicate this issue and found the root cause.

Please note the following.

**1. I am using a UIWebView. First of all, this is not recommended.**

**2. The following way of implementation causes this issue. I am writing pseudo-code here to demonstrate the problem.**

```
@implementation MyViewController

    - (void)loadView {

        //creating UIWebView Here
        self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:_some_frame];

        //setting the web view properties here.

        //Adding to the view
        [self.view addSubView: self.webView];

        [self populateWebView];
    }

    - (void) populateWebView {
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:_some_html 
                             baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_some_path]];
    }


    - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
        [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

        if (self.webView) {
           //The following two lines causing this issue.
           self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = _some_insets;
           self.webView.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = _some_insets;
        }
    }

@end
```

**3. The solution is given below.**

```
@implementation MyViewController

    - (void)loadView {

        //creating UIWebView Here
        self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:_some_frame];

        //setting the web view properties here.

        //Adding to the view
        [self.view addSubView: self.webView];

        [self populateWebView];
    }

    - (void) populateWebView {
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:_some_html 
                             baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_some_path]];
    }


    - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
        [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    }

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        webView.scrollView.contentInset = _some_insets;
        webView.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = _some_insets;
    }

@end
```

In my actual code, I was using a custom WebView class here by subclassing the **UIWebView**. Not think that will create some issue. The root cause is setting the "**contentInset**" and "**scrollIndicatorInsets**" in **viewDidLayoutSubviews** which is not a good idea. When I put the break points, "**viewDidLayoutSubviews**" called several times and eventually App crashes.

As a solution I moved the following part of the code into "**webViewDidFinishLoad**" which will call only when the WebView is ready after finished loading. So it makes sense to add this code under this delegate method.

```
webView.scrollView.contentInset = _some_insets;
webView.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = _some_insets;
```

Comment: Before knowing the root cause, I didn't know which part of my code is causing the problem and there was no information available in the Crash Reports as well.