# updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews ios10 crash

Tags: crash, scrollview, ios10

In My HockeyApp crash reports, I am getting the following crash in iOS10. Not sure what is the reason behind this.

```
Thread 10 Crashed:

0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000187346f30 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                                0x000000018e972bd8 updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews + 184
2   UIKit                                0x000000018e972cdc updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews + 444
3   UIKit                                0x000000018e972cdc updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews + 444
4   UIKit                                0x000000018e972cdc updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews + 444
5   UIKit                                0x000000018e972cdc updateSubviewsOfScrollContentViews + 444
6   UIKit                                0x000000018e972ad0 -[UIWebBrowserView _collectAdditionalSubviews] + 380
7   UIKit                                0x000000018e972924 -[UIWebDocumentView _updateSubviewCaches] + 52
8   UIKit                                0x000000018e79493c -[UIWebDocumentView subviews] + 88
9   UIKit                                0x000000018ea45bd4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) _wantsReapplicationOfAutoLayoutWithLayoutDirtyOnEntry:] + 68
10  UIKit                                0x000000018e741770 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1248
11  QuartzCore                           0x000000018bc0a40c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
12  QuartzCore                           0x000000018bbff0e8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 288
13  QuartzCore                           0x000000018bbfefa8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
14  QuartzCore                           0x000000018bb7bc64 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 248
15  QuartzCore                           0x000000018bba30d0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 508
16  QuartzCore                           0x000000018bba3af0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 116
17  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001888a97dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
18  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001888a740c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
19  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001887d6068 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
20  WebCore                              0x000000018d377a2c RunWebThread(void*) + 452
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018798f860 _pthread_body + 236
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018798f770 _pthread_start + 280
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018798cdbc thread_start + 0
```

Any suggestions will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to change the frame of an object that has Auto Layout constraints in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered in the following post.

[UIWebDocumentView _updateSubviewCaches crash in iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527107/uiwebdocumentview-updatesubviewcaches-crash-in-ios10/39913096#39913096)

The root cause for these issues are same.